# How to get exactly the same environment from 64 bit IIS Express to 64 bit IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7, 32bit-64bit, iis-express, oracleclient

I am migrating a web site from IIS Express to IIS. I got an exception:

NHibernate.ADOException: cannot open connection ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.

I have both oracle 32 and 64 client. The web site is running good with IIS Express. I made IIS app pool to use 64 bit. I noticed the code load System.Data.OracleClient.dll from GAC_64. And nothing was from GAC_32. Why the exception said 32 bit was used? Is there a way to tell the difference between the IIS and IIS Express configuration?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved by installing 64 bit ODAC (ODAC121024_x64) and replacing Oracle.DataAccess.dll under installation directory.

I still don't know whey IIS Express can work but IIS cannot though.